# Debugging GWT with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gwt

How can I setup GWT debugging in Eclipse?

This is the tutorial I am using:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/debug.html

I tried firefox and also chrome. Eclipse is uptodate and also the GWT-plugin. I googled for some solution, but I found only old discussions, nothing usefull. As far I can see, it should work out of the box, like descripted in the tutorial.

When I set a breakpoint, nothing happens, but the tutorial tells that eclipse should change to debug-perspective.

Solution:

Finally I got the debugger to work. I switched to the current plugin like Knarf told me in his answer.

The tutorial I was using was wrong (or just old). The debugger is not started automatically. You have to right click at the application url and then choose: "Open with SDBG Chrome JS Debugger"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin you are trying to use is the old plugin.

Try this plugin : https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

Check the YouTube videos on how to set it up : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU7ZQVLR5Zo&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I can start the debugger with the new plugin.